# Doubts about code to remove part of the text in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the following code that I found on a website, it monitors a folder and saves a log in .csv. However, I need the log to contain only the name of the file I saved, without the path and extension

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
$Watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$Watcher.Path = "C:\Users\some_profile\Desktop\iguaracu_pr"
$Watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
$Action = {
  $Path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
  $ChangeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
  $LogLine = "$ChangeType, $Path"
  Add-Content "C:\Users\some_profile\Pictures\Duvidas\log.csv" -Value $LogLine
}
    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher "Created" -Action $Action
Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher "Changed" -Action $Action
Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher "Deleted" -Action $Action
Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher "Renamed" -Action $Action

while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

I tried to use some codes I found on another forum but they didn't work, I hope someone with more knowledge can help me

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Check Event Viewer for errors if you do not get any with PS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemeventargs?view=net-8.0 it looks like you need to change `FullPath` to `Name` to just get the file without the path information.

That still leaves you with the file extension. If this was a straight forward `Get-ChildItem` output you could simply query `BaseName` rather than `Name` to get the filename without the extension, but in this instance I don't think that's an option, which just leaves doing a string replacement to remove the last characters from the name. Not tested, but this may do the trick.

```
### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
                $path = $path -replace ".{4}$"
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $logline = "$changeType, $path"
                Add-content "C:\Users\rodrigo.lurnadelli\Pictures\Duvidas\log.csv" -value $logline
              }
```

Note, the `-replace` just removes the last four characters from the end of the filename, eg `.txt`, which assumes the file has a normal 3 character extension. If it is a longer extension then you'll still have some of the extension showing. For instance `myfile.jpg` becomes `myfile`, but `myfile.jpeg` becomes `myfile.`

Comment: Thank you very much!
Helped me a lot.
Can you tell me if there is a way to export the file in .xlsx instead of .csv?

Comment: @RodrigoLunardelli You'll wanna check out [ImportExcel's `Export-Excel`](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel?tab=readme-ov-file#create-a-spreadsheet)

Comment: Thanks, but how would I use it in this code I have?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension("C:\full\path\to\MyfileName.txt")
```

Returns - **MyfileName**